# preg_match a <title=""> tag and display

Tags: php

Im trying to get the text inbetween a  tag. Heres what I have so far:

```
$new4 = '><strong> Rating:</strong><span> <span class="rl s5" title="A 5 Star(s)">A';

preg_match('/title="(.*?)">">/', $new4, $output);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

All im getting is a blank array, not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: You don't have `<title=` in `$new4`. You also could put the `preg_match` in a conditional then you would know when your regex worked and when it didn't. `if (preg_match('/title="(.*?)">">/', $new4, $output)) { print_r($output); } else { echo 'no matches :(';}`

Comment: Okay, with your update you don't have `">">` in `$new4`. You have answer below that should work for the provided example. If there is more to your question please post the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/title="(.*?)"/', $new4, $output);
```